# Get firebase snapshot data in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I'm new to Android & I don't know how to get all the firebase snapshot data at once inside the UID in the single data class.

```
  val usersPrivateRef = Constants.FIREBASE_RESIDENT_PRIVATE
    usersPrivateRef?.child("Fs0qczU3GsfJuGDGAeEN7bIgfjD3")
        ?.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.exists()) {
                        println(snapshot)
                    } else {
                        showLongToast("Snapshot not exists")
                    }
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have found a solution for my above question**
With the help of Gson library & also I have created the Kotlin data classes same as my snapshot data.

```
private var residentDATA : ArrayList<MineUserInfo> = ArrayList<MineUserInfo>()

var gson = Gson()
val json = Gson().toJson(snapshot.value)
var data = gson?.fromJson(json, MineUserInfo::class.java)
residentDATA.add(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

To get a value from the `DataSnapshot` you can use its `child()` and `getValue` calls. For example, to print Krishna's email, you'd do:

```
println(snapshot.child("personalDetails/email").getValue(String::class.java)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I know how to get specific values from snapshot.
  My question is how to store the snapshot data into the data class.

  Actually, I'm already doing it in iOS/Swift but I don't know how to do this in Android.

Comment: You might want to show that code in your question, instead of in a comment here.